# How to get fields from a String?

Tags: java

I have this String:

```
0104120002031190312181225100411040311105000623                       07164130140000000272080420120900100101103121120429821320                  "
```

It is coded TLV, meaning Tag, Length, Value.

```
01 04 1200
02 03 119
03 12 181221154028       
04 03 111
05 00 
06 23                        
07 16 4130140000000272          
08 04 2012                       
09 00 
10 01 0                             
11 03 121                          
12 04 2982                     
13 20
```

Now, I need some way to go through the String and extract the values of the tags depending o their length.
NB: the String is a response from a server and the length of each field could change.

I already tried to use methods such `substring` and `index` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What else you have about this link? Any key that index the breaking point?

Comment: Is 05 00 valid case ? If yes then what length does it refer to ??

Comment: Please explain ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Post your code and error/exception/different result you are getting. Also `06 23` doesn't match your description since there is no value after it. Same for `13 20`.

Comment: You can use `substring` or any numeric sequence here. Look at the line `11 03 121 ` If you are following a numeric sequence it will result `11 03` then `12 1 12042982`. You should get a response with a key to break this `string`

Comment: Does the tag always has 2 chars?

Comment: 05 00 means the tag 05 has no data

Comment: 06 23 and 13 20 are filled with spaces.

Comment: yes , Haytam, the tag always has 2chars.

Answer (score 2):

Based on example you have shared, it seems that tag and length of value is represented by 2 characters resp.

If that is the case, than you could do something as below

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ){
                String tag = input.substring(i,i+2);
                String len = input.substring(i+2, i + 4);
                String value = input.substring(i+4, Integer.parseInt(len));
                i += 4 + Integer.parseInt(len);
        }
```

Also, above solution is for a single string input. What can be done is split the input string over " ", and do the same loop-over process over that String array obtained after splitting

Comment: Are you sure about `i++` here?

Comment: need to check for those spaces

Comment: @Pshemo, Thanks, you were right. Updated my ans

Comment: @ecle, Noted. But it was just an idea as to what can be done. My answer was not intended to give exact solution, but give a possible approach

Comment: @ecle It seems that spaces are simply part of value, there is no need to handle them specially.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with
I refactor the str input a little bit because it's not a valid input

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "01041200"
            + "0203119"
            + "0312181225100411"
            + "0403111"
            + "0500"
            + "0623                       "
            + "07164130140000000272"
            + "08042012"
            + "0900"
            + "10010"
            + "1103121"
            + "12042982"
            + "1300";
    Map<String, String> tagValueMap = new HashMap<>();
    int tagLength = 2;
    int lengthLength = 2;
    int index = 0;
    while(index < str.length()) {
        String tag = str.substring(index, index+tagLength);
        int length = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index+tagLength,index+tagLength+lengthLength));
        String value = str.substring(index+tagLength+lengthLength, index+tagLength+lengthLength+length);
        tagValueMap.put(tag, value);
        index += length +tagLength+lengthLength;
    }
    System.out.println(tagValueMap);
}
```

The result is

```
{11=121, 01=1200, 12=2982, 02=119, 13=, 03=181225100411, 04=111, 05=, 06=                       , 07=4130140000000272, 08=2012, 09=, 10=0}
```

Hope it help

---

you can try it [here](https://ideone.com/LYguMk)

Comment: thank you for your help , but i can't devide the String like u did in the begining everytime i get a response from the server. the length and the data change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scanner whose delimiter you've set to the empty string in order to read the input character by character. Read the first two characters as the tag, the next two as the length, parse that one into an int and iterate over its amount to retrieve the value :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String tag = sc.next() + sc.next();
    int length = Integer.parseInt(sc.next() + sc.next());
    String value = "";
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        value+=sc.next();
    }
}
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/Hx5QTS).

Comment: thank you for responding , but the problem is that i don't have delimiters in the String thet i get from the server.

Comment: @lamyae check the ideone link, I've used just what you had as input. The point is to use the empty string as a delimiter so that the `scanner.next()` return a single character (since there's an empty string between each character) rather than the usual full word.